# How to deduce template parameter in explicit specialization of function template?

Tags: c++, template-specialization

Consider following case:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T> void f(T) { std::cout << "#1\n"; } // #1
template <> void f(const int) { std::cout << "#2\n"; } // #2

int main() {
    f<const int>(1); // call #1
    f<int>(1);       // call #2
    return 0;
}
```

It seems #2 is `f<int>(const int)` instead of `f<const int>(const int)`. What happens here? My first thought was top level `const` is discarded in function type transformation, so that the type of #2 is `void(int)`, which results in a specialization of `f<int>(const int)`. But I'm not sure about that.

And why C++ allows such syntax? I mean since we can't partial specialize function templates, we would have known the template argument value if we want to explicitly specialize one. So why C++ don't just force programmer explicitly provides template argument values when specializing template functions? (i.e. we would have to write specialization of #1 in `template <> void f<int>(const int) { }` or `template <> void f<int const>(const int) { }`) Does it have special usage except for coding convenience?

Answer (score 6):

```
void f(const int p)
```

Setting aside the issue of templates, for the moment, the `const` part here does not specify the type of the parameter to `f()`. All that `const` here specifies is that `p` is `const` inside the function `f()`. The type of the parameter to `f()` is `int`.

```
template <> void f(const int)
```

When the compiler is trying to deduce the type of the specialization, it deduces that since the function parameter's type is `int`, this must be a specialization for `f<int>`.

Can't really make deduction work this way. You have to be explicit, if that's what you want to do:

```
template <> void f<const int>(const int) { std::cout << "#2\n"; }
```